# Nuke BlinkScript: Why does the convolution kernel scale down the image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, kernel, convolution, nuke

The access pattern argument **eAccessRanged2D** is causing the image to be "scaled down" from 1920 x 1080 to roughly around 960 x 540. The code is written for Blinkscript Nuke application. All the code is doing is passing src to dst without any modification?

```
kernel Halation_kernel : ImageComputationKernel<ePixelWise> {
Image<eRead, eAccessRanged2D, eEdgeClamped> src;
Image<eWrite, eAccessPoint> dst;

void process(int2 pos) {
    dst() = src(pos.x, pos.y);

}
```

I tried setting `Image<eWrite, eAccessRanged2d> dst;` and `dst (pos.x, pos.y) = src(pos.x, pos.y)` which fixed the scaling issue, but changed the color of the whole image.

Scaling issue:

[image]

Color issue after changing dst to eRangedAccess:
[image]

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. There is not nearly enough code there to see what you are doing.

Comment: that's not "scaling", that's some type of screwup in how you access the pixels, how the pixel format is interpreted, etc. -- you should take this to whatever community support is hosted by The Foundry -- [mre] also implies debugging, i.e. strip the business logic out of your kernel, start with an identity operation.

Comment: I think you or a colleague asked this same question before. it's the same program, same effect, also mentioning "halation"

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Apologies for the subpar formatting of the question. I'm very new to coding and the respective coding forums. I hope the edit I made to the question makes it much more readable. I have also put the question on the Foundry forum,  but I thought that I would have a better chance of obtaining replies on this forum.

Comment: I said “There is not nearly enough code there” so you remove most of the code and leave only five lines. 

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah yeah sorry I was confused about that because reading the debugging and MRE site it said to minimizes as much as possible to a state that still produces the same error, but is still readable. I also felt like that was what Christoph Rackwitz was suggesting. I have now minimized it to those view lines (that’s the whole Code) and the error still persists.

Comment: *very* likely an issue with how the kernel is invoked. this is a problem exclusive to this Nuke BlinkScript thing. it's not a matter of image processing itself. I doubt there's anyone here who knows this thing. -- in its current form, this question is unanswerable.